# Apache camel get path of exchange

Tags: java, file, path, apache-camel

I use apache camel to monitor my file system
I use following route:

```
public class FsRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            while(true){
            FsProcessor processor = new FsProcessor();
            from("file:C:\\Users\\My_User_Name\\Documents\\TRAX_PAYMENTS\\KBC?noop=true&idempotent=false").process(processor);
        }
        }
    }
```

This route calls following processor

```
public class FsProcessor implements Processor {
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {}
}
```

Now what I want to do is to get the path of an exchange. This because I want to monitor it and the path is a unique key. Is there a property or a way to get the path of the exchange?

Comment: Do you mean the file name you want to get or what? And btw you should not do a while loop in the route builder - that is totally wrong.!

Comment: Yes I mean the file. An exchange is a file which is added or deleted in a folder, the path is the unique key of a file. What is wrong about an infinite loop if you want to monitor all the time? grtz

Comment: The route builder is for setting up the route, at runtime the route keeps running until you stop the route or camel itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file path from the processor as shown

```
public class FsProcessor implements Processor {
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
    String path = file.getPath();
  }
}
```

It uses Camel's type converter,

- http://camel.apache.org/type-converter

So if you wanted the content of the file as a byte[] or String, you could do

```
String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```